# Elements side by side?

Tags: css, html

I have a h1 and a nav element. I wish for them to sit side by side.

How can I do this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVveW/).

```
<header>
<h1>This is the title</h1>
<nav>
    <span id="search"><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"></div>
    <span id="btn-close">&times;</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: add float: left to them.

Comment: As a start you could validate your html.  Your spans are being closed with divs.

Comment: you can use [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/hVveW/5/)

Comment: …and after doing so, learn how to use search engine.

Comment: Easy rep up for grabs people...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you might be looking after:

```
h1{
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

nav{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q8D9/1/)

Comment: +1, "_inline elements cannot have width_", you are right of course. Wasnt really thinking about the widths when I changed the fiddle, `inline-block` is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
h1{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

nav{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're closing your `span`s with `div`.

It should be:

```
<header>
  <h1>This is the title</h1>
  <nav>
    <span id="search"><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"></span>
    <span id="btn-close">&times;</span>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Secondly, you have a few options to get them side by side:

You can do this:

```
h1, nav{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hVveW/22/)

or:

```
h1, nav{
  display:inline;
  width:50%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hVveW/21/)

If two css elements are going to have the same rules, you can put them together by putting a `,` in between elements (like above examples).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVveW/19/)***</kbd>
*CSS*

```
h1{
    display:inline;
}
nav{
    display:inline;
}
```